# Crash on email detection in TextInput on Xiaomi devices running android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, inputbox, xiaomi

When we type email address on input box we are getting error as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke direct method 'void android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.initDrawables()' on a null object reference
at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.access$300(Editor.java:6726)
at android.widget.Editor.getEmailPopupWindow(Editor.java:1476)
at android.widget.Editor.showEmailPopupWindow(Editor.java:1484)
at android.widget.Editor.handleEmailPopup(Editor.java:1463)
at android.widget.Editor.updateCursorPosition(Editor.java:2106)
at android.widget.TextView.getUpdatedHighlightPath(TextView.java:7824)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:8009)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21628)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4409)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4382)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20457)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:575)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:581)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3713)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3508)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1800)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7792)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1031)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:854)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1016)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

We tried to fix it by adding following code

```
import { Platform, TextInput } from 'react-native';
```

const { Version } = Platform;

const brandsNeedingWorkaround = ['redmi', 'xiaomi', 'poco', 'pocophone'];
const needsXiaomiWorkaround = brandsNeedingWorkaround.includes(RNInfo.getBrand().toLowerCase())
&& Version > 28;

const InputTextWrapper = forwardRef(({ onFocus, caretHidden, ...others }, ref) => {
const [hackCaretHidden, setHackCaretHidden] = useState(needsXiaomiWorkaround ? true : caretHidden);

```
const handleFocus = useCallback(() => {
    if (needsXiaomiWorkaround) {
        setHackCaretHidden(caretHidden);
    }
    if (onFocus) onFocus();
}, [onFocus, caretHidden]);

return (
    <TextInput
        ref={ref}
        {...others}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        caretHidden={hackCaretHidden}
    />
);
```

});

But still it is not working. Please provide us a solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this can help you

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27204#issuecomment-556998391

Some developers get it working playing with the 'editable' prop in TextInput

```
const [editable, setEditable] = React.useState(false)

React.useEffect(() => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setEditable(true)
  }, 100)
}, [])

return (
  <TextInput
    editable={editable}
    ...
  />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply

```
const [editable, setEditable] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setEditable(true);
  }, []);

<TextInput
editable={editable}
/>
```

also solves it for me